# Filter a SharePoint(table) View based on click - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sharepoint

I was hoping to get some help with some jQuery, and am interested in understanding the solution to the problem.
Basically, I have a SharePoint list, which is holding two instances of the same table.
[The table in black is the same table below just modified, I want the user to be able to click on the season "SS17" or "FW17" and filter the below table by the item they click on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abYAK.png%5C)

Currently I used CSS to set the second table display: none; and here is the jQuery I use to toggle the table when clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".ms-vb2").click(function(){
    $('#scriptWPQ5').slideToggle("slow");
}); });
```

Currently it is toggling the table fine, where ".ms-vb2" is the top table in black, and where '#scriptWPQ5' is the bottom table that is being toggled. I wanted to take it a step further and filter it based on what the "Season" the user clicked!

Thank you for your time, and I hope you can help me learn jQuery and understand tables :)
Let me know if I need to add anymore information!

EDIT - Here is the HTML for the first table, the first row "SS17" is highlighted, and the other row "FW17" is outlined in red.
[Table 1 HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1YLW.png)

I do not have the ability to post more than 2 links, but will delete the first link if I need to, in order to post the HTML of the second table.  The second table is identical to the Table 1 HTML though.

Comment: The provided description is ok, but you can not be helped unless you provide enough code here. Post your HTML/CSS and JQuery. Better if you could create a similar [**demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)** or provide a **Live Link**.

Comment: Didn't got you. Link of? **Live Link = Online link if you have it on server.**

Comment: Sorry about that, I can not post more than 2 links, but have added the HTML for the first table.  Does this help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution,

this allows you to click on TRs from table1, and trigger rows to hide and show in table2.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .highlight{
            background-color: yellow;
            font-size:24px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<table border="1" id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>ss17</td>
        <td>def</td>
        <td>ghi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss18</td>
        <td>def</td>
        <td>ghi</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss19</td>
        <td>def</td>
        <td>ghi</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<table border="1" id="table2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Season</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Model</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>ss17</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss17</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss17</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss18</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss18</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss18</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss19</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss19</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss19</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss17</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss17</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss17</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss18</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss18</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss18</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss19</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss19</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss19</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss17</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss17</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss17</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss18</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss18</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss18</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss19</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss19</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss19</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss17</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss17</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss17</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss18</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss18</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss18</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss19</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss19</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss19</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss17</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss17</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss17</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss18</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss18</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss18</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss19</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss19</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss19</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss17</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss17</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss17</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss18</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss18</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss18</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss19</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss19</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ss19</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>1234</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>


    $('#table2 tbody tr').hide();

    $('#table1 tr').click(function () {

        var trClickedValue = $(this).children('td:eq(0)').html();

        $(this).attr('data',trClickedValue); // set ATTR
        var dataValue = $(this).attr('data'); // get ATTR

        $('#table2 tbody tr').each(function(){

            var tr = $(this);
            var tdValue = tr.children('td:eq(0)').html();

            if(tdValue != dataValue)
            {
                tr.hide();
                tr.removeClass('highlight');
            }
            else
            {
                tr.toggle();
                tr.addClass('highlight');
            }
        })
    })

</script>

</body>
</html>
```